# error ModuleNotFoundError in django for python

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I am getting the following error when running my code:

```
  File "C:\Users\emanull\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'current_datetime'
```

My file views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from datetime

def current_datetime(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    html = "<html><body>It is now %s.</body></html>" % now
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

My file urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('time/', include('views.current_datetime'))
]
```

Comment: please paste the related code here - your github link is broken

Comment: Sorry, the link has been corrected

Comment: first of all - your import is incorrect `from datetime` ->  `import datetime`

Comment: I fixed this but I still get the above error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My file views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import datetime

def current_datetime(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    html = "<html><body>It is now %s.</body></html>" % now
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

My file urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from gogle import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('time/', views.current_datetime)
]
```

- In your `views.py` you can either:

  `from datetime import datetime` and use `datetime.now()`

  or

  `import datetime` and use `datetime.datetime.now()`
- In your `urls.py` use an [absolute import](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/) along with the correct syntax according to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#example) ([include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs) expects a local `urls.py` not a view).

> Whenever Django encounters include(), it chops off whatever part of
> the URL matched up to that point and sends the remaining string to the
> included URLconf for further processing.

Comment: I see you are showing the updated lines by commenting and replacing them, but it would be much more better to be explicit about them and point the changes out.

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in your views.py file. The `from datetime` is incorrect since you are not importing anything **from** the datetime package.

The correct usage in your case would be `import datetime`.

Your second error is how you are using the URLs. This needs to be:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('time/', views.current_datetime, name='current-datetime'),
]
```

See the [Django documentation for URLs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/urls/) for further reading.

Comment: I fixed this but I still get the above error

Comment: @emanuel I've updated the answer, you use `include(...)` when you want to include the urls.py file from another app, not the same app.

Answer (score 1):

Two things you need to do.

1. fix the below line in your import code, replace
   `from datetime` by `import datetime`
2. make sure you have the blank **init**.py file located in the same folder where views.py is, and then you can do like below:

> ```
> from . import views
>
> urlpatterns = [
>     path('time/', include('views.current_datetime'))
> ]
> ```